# Scheme/Drracket, avoid using let, still not evaluating same function twice

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, let

I have a coding class assignment i am not able to solve :(

```
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    (i (g x) (h (g x)))))
```

i, g and h are just arbitrary function names.
This is the code and i am required to rewrite it such that `(g x)` is evaluated only once but without using let (or any variant of it) using only `define` and `lambda` as predefined functions. I am also not allowed to take calculations out of `f`, that is, alls calculations must happen inside that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is

```
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    (define intermediary (g x))
    (i intermediary (h intermediary))))
```

and the more complicated would be

```
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    ((lambda (intermediary) ; anonymous procedure
       (i intermediary (h intermediary)))
     (g x))))
```

or, avoiding the anonymous procedure and giving it the name *sub*:

```
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    (define sub
      (lambda (intermediary)
       (i intermediary (h intermediary))))
    (sub (g x))))
```

Comment: Be sure to give uselpa credit for your answer, in class!

Answer (score 2):

Funny how you are not allowed to use any variants of `let` while `define` and `lambda` is allowed, which I would certainly say are true variants of `let` (or vice versa).

```scm
(let ((v1 expr1) ...)
  body ...)
```

is the same as

```scm
((lambda (v1 ...)
   body ...) expr1 ...)
```

So `let` is a variant of `lambda`.. Thus:

```scm
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    (let ((gx (g x)))
      (i gx (h gx)))))
```

Can of course be rewritten to:

```scm
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    ((lambda (gx)
       (i gx (h gx)))
     (g x))))
```

Now Imagine that before `(define f ..)` we define the other freee variables. That can be rewritten to:

```scm
((lambda (i)
   ((lambda (h)
      ((lambda (g)
         ((lambda (f)
            rest-of-program ...)
          (lambda (x)
            ((lambda (gx)
               (i gx (h gx)))
             (g x)))))
       (lambda (v) g-expression)))
    (lambda (v) h-expression)))
 (lambda (v1 v2) i-expression))
```

The real expansion might be slightly more complex if one of the bound variables actually needed to have a binding that were further in in it's closure, but for primitives this works.